# Confusion over using Qemu in Docker

Tags: linux, docker, qemu, arm, emulation

I'm currently learning to build ARM Docker images on x86 hosts machines. I found [this guide](https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/27/running-and-building-arm-docker-containers-in-x86/), as well as a couple others which basically all say the same thing. They are all a few years old, so the answer to this question might as well be that either Qemu or Docker doesn't work that way anymore, but I wan't able to verify that.

Basically, you have to do two things:

1. Install the `qemu-user-binfmt` package. This will create a file named `/proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/qemu-arm` with the following content:

   ```
   enabled
   interpreter /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static
   flags: OCF
   offset 0
   magic 7f454c4601010100000000000000000002002800
   mask ffffffffffffff00fffffffffffffffffeffffff
   ```
2. Install the `qemu-user-static` package to get the `/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static` interpreter. This will remove the previous package, but the `binfmt`-entry will stay.

---

The guide then goes on to say that in order to build an ARM image, you have to copy the interpreter from step 2 to the same location it has on your system within the image, and in order to run an ARM image you have to mount the two copies using the option `-v /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static`.

To test this I created two images, `qemu-test` and `qemu-test:noqemu`, with the following Dockerfiles (I copied the interpreter into my working directory):

`qemu-test`:

```
FROM armv7/armhf-ubuntu

COPY qemu-arm-static /usr/bin

CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo 'Hello World'"]
```

`qemu-test:noqemu`:

```
FROM armv7/armhf-ubuntu

CMD ["sh", "-c", "echo 'Hello World'"]
```

---

I then tried the following four commands (still on my x86 machine):

```
docker run qemu-test
docker run -v /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static qemu-test
docker run qemu-test:noqemu
docker run -v /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static:/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static qemu-test:noqemu
```

And to my suprise, **they all worked**. As long as the `binfmt`-entry was present, that is. When I removed it, none of them worked. I also ran both images on an ARM machine, where they also both worked.

This leads me to my question(s): **What's the actual point of putting the interpreter into the image? And what is the point of mounting it? Do I even need Qemu at all?** Remember that those guides are a couple years old. If the answer is indeed "stuff doesn't work that way anymore", I would also be interested in how it does work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single important field in the binfmt_misc kernel module config, the flag `F`. That flag indicates the path to the interpreter is fixed regardless of the mount namespace. Otherwise, when a file is encountered that appears to be for another platform, binfmt will look for the interpreter (`/usr/bin/qemu-arm-static`) in the same mount namespace as the command you are attempting to run, and you'll get a `file not found` error.

Part of the install for `qemu-user-static` is to run `update-binfmts` which needs the `--fix-binary` flag. This is typically done in newer versions of the package to handle the docker use case, but if you have an old version, you'll encounter the issue like [this bug report describes](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu/+bug/1815100).

Once you have this properly configured, my preferred way to build images for other platforms is to use buildkit, and docker makes this accessible with their buildx CLI. With buildkit, you get variables to select the platform for individual stages (it may be faster to download some binaries with your native platform and then copy them over to the target image). For more on buildx, see [docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/).

Comment: Ok so if I remove the `F` flag, all but the third command I listed at the end of my question work. So if I get this right, in order to build an ARM image on a x86 machine, you don't need virtualization at all (apart from Docker of course). Only when you want to build the an ARM image that is supposed to also be executed on an x86 you need to put in Qemu.

Comment: @TigersEye120 The only need for any emulation is to be able to run commands for a different platform. You'll want that to run the container, or any build that includes a "RUN" step. If the Dockerfile only has entries like "COPY" and "FROM" steps, you never touch qemu.